# Travis ci no such file or directory error with secure environment variable

Tags: django, environment-variables, travis-ci

I am trying to add a secure environment variable to my .travis.yml file. However, whenever it is run the build fails with the output `/home/travis/build.sh: line 128: my_secret_key}: No such file or directory` where **my_secret_key** is the string returned by travis encrypt`.

I have verified that my .travis.yml file is valid with the `travis-lint` command.

**EDIT:**
My Travis build is located at https://travis-ci.org/Aaron1011/texting_wall

Comment: Is this for a build on travis-ci.org? If so, could you point me towards the repository and failing builds, so I can have a peek? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You placed the secure environment variables in the `before_script` block, so travis tries to execute it. You probably want to place them in the `env` block, and all the other environment variables, too:

```
language: python
python:
  - "2.7"
env:
  global:
    - DISPLAY=:99.0
    - secure: "mbnS2lycZn6/7jKjRf7c5yqQtQXYXBqhzy/FzCuDY9se8t3JxrRL6TUMFZcs\nDl2gJTx6pwjl4DqIUqKkS8tjBdy6zgtq1mDwUrxKwKreIHRo1YPl8hvDDJEz\nnMja/tzVoUA4EFdvyK46srklQHs18S2OKMmMQCa921TAFEOIv5A="
    - secure: "iroiS72GhQgKzj7rm+1GoKHkLi4sYXdsdo6Ebe5v6C5lgSBFQ11yWiSQxATt\nxsfzfAF3MyG21lnM/bttUQTP4kJ8DIotLlqmz8+HUYMXZQCZWE9WAfDfDqqJ\nIdeHnet8NuRslJGObkejt/BG8/5Rggbnav9yRhOL3lzeamiVVqY="
  matrix: 
    - DJANGO_VERSION=1.4.1 RACK_ENV=test


before_script:
  - "sh -e /etc/init.d/xvfb start"
  - sleep 3
  - "python manage.py runserver &"
  - sleep 5

script:
  - "python manage.py test main"
```

[See the documenation](http://about.travis-ci.org/docs/user/build-configuration/#Environment-variables) for the difference betwwen `global` and `matrix` environment variables.

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe that I missed that!